# Selenium Python. Selenium не переходит по гиперссылке

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Я захожу на сайт, авторизуюсь, после чего мне нужно перейти по гиперссылке (сразу после авторизации).Сначала попробовал использовать этот `self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//li[@id="{}"]/a[1]'.format(SIDEBAR[page])))).click()` код, но он работает, только если перед его использованием прописать `time.sleep(5)`, то есть пока страница полностью у меня не загрузится.

Сейчас использую

`self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//li[@id="{}"]/a[1]'.format(SIDEBAR[page]))))
self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//li[@id="{}"]/a[1]'.format(SIDEBAR[page])).click()`

Данный код работает через раз (образно говоря),либо все работает правильно, либо бывают случаи, когда гиперссылка просто подсвечивается, будто мышкой к ней подвели, но не нажали.

Так же у меня прописан `self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)` без него не работает. И `self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser,10)`
В качестве драйвера я использую `Firefox`

Comment: @Kaznachel используйте webDriverWait для ожидания объекта в течении некоторого времени

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/273089/